# .splice(x,1) not working

Tags: arrays, node.js, array-splice

I giving my first steps using Node JS and things were going ok until I faced a strange behaviour that I cannot neither understand nor find an workaround for it.
It should be so simple, everything is well documented and I can find so many examples of this working that I may be missing something very obvious, unfortunately. After loosing almost 2 days around this I decided to ask for some help... thanks in advance.

I am trying to store objects (clientID, socket info) in an array and want to remove an object when the connection gets lost.

I've build a small subset of my code that replicates the behaviour.

```
var socket = require('socket.io');

var machines = [];
var mach1 = [new socket(), new socket()];
var mach2 = [new socket(), new socket()];
var mach3 = [new socket(), new socket()];

machines["357973049420265"] = mach1;
machines["357973049420266"] = mach2;
machines["357973049420267"] = mach3;

console.log("Before : " + Object.keys(machines));
machines.splice(0,1);
console.log("After  : " + Object.keys(machines));
```

The result is:

```
Before : 357973049420265, 357973049420266, 357973049420267 
After  : 357973049420265, 357973049420266, 357973049420267
```

Any ideas?

Thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`machines` is an array, so you are setting `"357973049420265"` -- a string value -- as a key.  `.splice` will only alter *numeric* keys.

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but you either want to use `machines = {}` and remove properties via `delete` or use `.push` to add array elements to get `.splice` to work.

If you used an object you could do `delete machines[Object.keys(machines).slice(0, 1)]` to do what this code seems to be trying to do, but your ultimate goal is unclear.

Comment: Thank you so much. Problem solved with you tip. machines.splice(0,1) was replaced by delete machines["357973049420266"].